# How to recheck if Input is still empty

Tags: jquery, input

I'm struggling with this basic jQuery and I hope you can help out.

I have the following code which hides `#test` if it's empty. How do I change to show now, if the input is not longer empty.

```
jQuery(function ($){
  if($("#email").is(":empty")){
    var test = $("#test");
    $(test).hide();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following

```
$('#email').keyup(function(event) {
   var test = $('#test');
   if($(this).val() === '') {
      test.hide();
   } else {
      test.show();
   }
});
```

Comment: Doesn't change. Im pretty sure I have to add an eventlistener or so to recheck if someone typed anything

Answer (score 0):

As explained above you can use .val to check the the value, then you can use an if statement to show/hide based on whether email was empty or not.

```
        function ShowHide (){
            if($("#email").val() == ""){
                $("#test").hide();
            } else {
                $("#test").show();  
            }
```

you can then call this method in your html using onclick="ShowHide()"